# does not work to post to the database first click(second click work)

Tags: php, sql

I have a big problem. I have a feature where you should replace "password". but when the user clicks on submit first time, leaving Hands = "false" in var_dump. If you do the same process again and it works great! has any had a similar problem?

VIEW:

```
    public function View(){
    $NavigationView = New NavigationView();

    return "
    <div class='change'>
            <form name='login' id='RegisterUserForm' method='Post'  action='" . $NavigationView -> GetPersonIndex() . "'>
                <p>
                    <label class='label' for='password'><h2  id='changelabel' >New Password</h2></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type='password' size='20' name='$this->pass' id='name' class='text'/>
                </p>

                    <input type='hidden'  id='submithidden' value='true' name='" . NavigationView::Personindex . "'/>
                    <input type='submit'  name='submit' id='submit' value='Change Password'/>
            </form>
    </div>
    ";


}
```

CONTROLLER :

```
if($PersonChangeView->TriedToChangePassword()){
        var_dump($PersonChangeView->GetPassword(),$Username);
        $kalle = $UserHandler->ChangePassword($PersonChangeView->GetPassword(),$Username);
        var_dump($kalle);

    }
```

HANDLER:

```
    public function ChangePassword($password,$username){
    var_dump($password,$username);
    $DBConnection = new DBConnection();
    $DBConnection -> Connect();
    $sql= "UPDATE user SET m_password=? where m_username=?";
    $stmt = $DBConnection -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$password, $username);
    if ($stmt === FALSE) {
        //echoBr("prepare of '$sql' failed " .  $DBConnection -> error);
        return false;
    }
    $stmt -> execute();
    // ger resultet.
    $result = $stmt -> get_result();
    $stmt -> close();
    return false;


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you execute your scripts in the right order?
It seems like it worked the first time but the page was not retrieved with the new data. And only in the second time it shows you results from your first attempt actually.

You need to call your View after having modified the value in the Handler and Controller.